# Where to enable javascript in Superset for deckgl

Tags: javascript, apache-superset, deck.gl

I would like to enable javascript tooltip generator in deck.gl scatter.

[image]

I have added the following row in superset_config.py and run superset but it is still disabled. Please advise which location else that I need to modify.

`ENABLE_JAVASCRIPT_CONTROLS = True`
Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am facing the same problem. Have Enabled javascript controls in superset_config.py but am unable to add any javascript

Comment: not yet found the solution.

Comment: Did you restart after changing config.py, it works for me

Answer (score 2):

1. From you superset root path,
   `nano docker/pythonpath_dev/superset_config.py`
2. Look for `FEATURE_FLAGS`
3. You need to add the ENABLE_JAVASCRIPT_CONTROLS flag at the end of this. For example, if it already has ALERT_REPORTS

```
FEATURE_FLAGS = {"ALERT_REPORTS": True, "ENABLE_JAVASCRIPT_CONTROLS":True }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable it via an environment variable :
SUPERSET_FEATURE_ENABLE_JAVASCRIPT_CONTROLS=true

or via superset_config.py as mentionned by @Jayaram Kasi